# Is the effect of capacitors and inductors directly proportional to frequency?

Tags: capacitor, frequency, impedance, inductance

I'm reading Practical Electronics for Inventors and a curious sentence has come up.

> The effects of
>   capacitance and inductance are generally more significant at high frequencies

This makes sense to me for inductance, since it's directly proportional to frequency in the formula, but I was wondering why capacitance and its effect are also greater with increased frequency when in the formula \$\frac{1}{\omega \cdot C}\$
it's clear that the frequency is inversely proportional to the capacitor's impedance. Doesn't this mean that with greater frequencies the effect of the capacitor is lowering, which also means that for lower frequencies the capacitor's [edit:] effect increases?

Comment: Depends which "effects" they are talking about...

Comment: "does it's job better" is a meaningless statement. What "it's job" is depends on what you're doing with it.

Comment: Well I'm trying to understand that too. I edited the bad wording at the end. In the book the author is talking in general, there is no reference circuit to which he points when he says what's in the quotes up there in my original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the misunderstanding here is they wording only. The magnitude of the impedance of a capacitor goes down as frequency increase, as you have stated.

However the book's use of the word "effect" is the deviation from the DC steady state expected value. A capacitor at DC is an open circuit and the higher you raise the frequency the closer it looks like to a short circuit. An inductor, however,  looks like a short circuit in steady state DC but as the frequency increases it looks more and more like an open circuit.

These comments are only about the magnitude of the impedance.

Answer (score 2):

I think the book is talking about **parasitic** inductance and capacitance... because if you put a cap or inductor in your design, then the "effects" are wanted. When they are unwanted, stuff becomes interesting...

If you send a high frequency signal through a cable, then you'll be interested in the cable's capacitance, inductance, and transmission line effects.

Say you have a capacitor... at "high" frequencies, it becomes an inductor due to its parasitic ESL.

Say you have an inductor... at "high" frequencies, the parasitic capacitance between windings turns it into a capacitor. Then at even higher frequencies it becomes an inductor again, since even a short bit of wire has inductance.

Parasitic ESL/ESR/Capacitance become impossible to ignore at frequencies that depend on your design.

If you do average electronics, you may never notice. Stuff just works... everyone's happy.

On another forum, there was a guy wondering why fast SPI didn't work when funneled through a 10 meter cable.